# ZeroMQ: Same context for multiple sockets

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq, jzmq

I am trying to use ZeroMQ's pub-sub sockets. However, I don't clearly understand the role of context (`zmq::context_t`) while creating sockets (`zmq::socket_t`).

Assuming that I want to create 5 subscriber sockets (`zmq::socket_t` using `ZMQ_SUB`), do I need 5 contexts, one for each of the subscriber sockets? Or can I use a single context for all 5 sockets?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Assuming that I want to create 5 subscriber sockets ( `zmq::socket_t`
> `using` `ZMQ_SUB` ), do I need 5 contexts, one for each of the subscriber
> sockets? Or can I use a single context for all 5 sockets?

You need only one **`Context`** instance for this light-weight use-case. Check the part of documentation attached below explaining 0MQ context usage and an example I made for you attached at the end of this post.

> ZeroMQ applications always start by creating a context, and then using
> that for creating sockets. In C, it's the **`zmq_ctx_new()`** call. You
> should create and use exactly one context in your process.
> Technically, the context is the container for all sockets in a single
> process, and acts as the transport for **`inproc`** sockets, which are the
> fastest way to connect threads in one process. If at runtime a process
> has two contexts, these are like separate ZeroMQ instances.

I made an example for you below as a help for you in understanding `ZMQ context` and `ZMQ PUB-SUB` pattern. Creating 5 subscriber sockets is fine as long as you have 5 producing services. However if you have one source publishing notifications I would recommend using `PUB-SUB` pattern and filtering property of `ZMQ SUB` sockets. You can check how to set that up below in my code in communication between `publisher #1` and `subscriber`.

**Publisher #1 sends temperature and humidity updates..**

```py
import zmq
from time import sleep

# Server socket
context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
socket.bind( "tcp://*:5556" )

while True:
    socket.send_multipart( [ "TEMP", "25.40" ] )
    socket.send_multipart( [ "HUMD", "48.90" ] )
    sleep( 1 )
```

**Publisher #2 sends pressure updates..**

```py
import zmq
from time import sleep

# Server socket
context = zmq.Context()
socket2 = context.socket( zmq.PUB )
socket2.bind( "tcp://*:5557" )

while True:
    socket2.send_multipart( [ "PRSS", "10000.00" ] )
    sleep( 1 )
```

**Subscriber registered to temperature, humidity and pressure updates on two different servers..**

```py
import zmq
from time import sleep

# Sockets to talk to servers
context = zmq.Context()
socket  = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
socket.connect(  "tcp://localhost:5556" )
socket2 = context.socket( zmq.SUB )
socket2.connect( "tcp://localhost:5557" )

# Set filters
socket.setsockopt_string(  zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "TEMP".decode( 'ascii' ) )
socket.setsockopt_string(  zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "HUMD".decode( 'ascii' ) )
socket2.setsockopt_string( zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "PRSS".decode( 'ascii' ) )

poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register( socket,  zmq.POLLIN )
poller.register( socket2, zmq.POLLIN )

while True:
    socks = dict( poller.poll() )
    if socket in socks and socks[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
        [ measurement, value ] = socket.recv_multipart()
        print measurement
        print value

    if socket2 in socks and socks[socket2] == zmq.POLLIN:
        [ measurement, value ] = socket2.recv_multipart()
        print measurement
        print value

    sleep( 1 )
```

Comment: Thanks Krystian for the correct description and a simple example!

Comment: Sorry to revive such an old post, but is the `setsockopt_string` needed? I tried to reproduce just the `sub` part with an already registered `pub` socket, but failed and I don't know why. The only part I ommited was the `setsockopt_string`.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful answer. So each socket will have its own process, please?