# Having multiple sockets for same Context() and same port in ZMQ

Tags: sockets, zeromq, publish-subscribe, pyzmq

My current system takes input stream from cameras, each camera in a separate instance, and apply Computer Vision models on each camera (Object Detection, Object Tracking and Personnel Recognition), and then pass the results to a sink/master process that performs the rest of functionality over those results and I'm using `ZMQ` as an inter-process communication.

What I implemented now is that each worker connects to a different port, and then the sink subscribes to these ports independently, but this solution is not scalable, as we might have 3 or 4 cameras/worker, and I felt that it won't be efficient to keep opening ports like that.

[Multiple Ports Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BOjfY.png)
[image]

That's when I tried to implement `Multi-Pub/Single-Sub` module, where all workers will connect to one port and the sink will subscribe to that port only.

[Single Port Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFEyk.png)
[image]

The problem I faced is that I no longer can distinguish between different cameras since I'm receiving different footages in the same port which causes a problem in streaming them later, that's why I'm thinking about the possibility of having multiple sockets for each context, while each socket subscribes to a different IP, is that possible?

Note: I've seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32280271/zeromq-same-context-for-multiple-sockets) but it has different ports for different sockets which does not really serve my case.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q :** *" ...  I no longer can distinguish between different cameras ... "*

**A :**
Yet, there are ZeroMQ tools to do so - check details about :

- `.setsockopt( zmq.METADATA,  "X-key:value" )`
- `.setsockopt( zmq.ROUTING_ID, Id )`

As you see, `PUB/SUB`-archetype is the worst one to be used here ( you pay all the costs of TOPIC-filter based subscription-management, yet receive nothing for doing that ).

Using better matching archetypes is the way to go.

Given not performance details were posted, the capacity may soon get over-saturated, so may use more specific steps to flatten the workload and protect smooth-flow of the service :

- `.setsockopt( zmq.TOS,        aTransportPath_TOS )`
- `.setsockopt( zmq.MAXMSGSIZE, aBLOB_limit_to_save_RAM )`

Given a streaming could block on many "old"-frames not having got through the e2e-pipeline in due time, it might make sense to also set this :

- `.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE,   1 )`

As you can see, there are many smart details in the configuration space of the ZeroMQ, plus once scaling is to grow larger and larger, your design shall also fine-tune the `Context()`-engine performance once instantiating :

- `.Context( aNumOfContextIOthreads2use )`

Comment: Thank you! I will read more about ZMQ methods and options you mentioned. But can I know why `PUB/SUB-archetype is the worst one to be used here`? I used it because it is the faster approach as other approached requires a kind of third step (confirmation of message delivery) while I want to publish the message (frame) blindly to assure that I will stream them with no huge delay.

Comment: Can you please explain what `.setsockopt( zmq.TOS,        aTransportPath_TOS )
.setsockopt( zmq.MAXMSGSIZE, aBLOB_limit_to_save_RAM )` mean please?

Comment: Also, for `.setsockopt( zmq.METADATA,  "X-key:value" )
.setsockopt( zmq.ROUTING_ID, Id )` please, they can be used to help us to distinguish frames?